# Как отменить свойство max-width?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Так как в другом разрешение экрана нужно выровнять текст по центру, но текст из-за ограничения по ширине, игнорирует это свойство, margin:auto не выручает..

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `max-width: none` что ли?

Comment: `max-width: unset`

Comment: none и unset, тоже не решают проблемы

Answer (score 0):

```
Я решил проблему с помощью создания главного класса и центрировал его с помощью 

.center__column{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```